# I want to change comment using query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table called phase with following fields.
ID,Name.
I want to change its comment using query.

```
ALTER TABLE phase 
CHANGE Name Name VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL  COMMENT Hello world
```

But its not useful for me as i wont be able to generate similar query from my php application.
Help needed....

Comment: So then don't do it in PHP? *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE `phase` CHANGE `Name` `Name` VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL COMMENT 'comment here...'
```

#### Update

Try this, in your PHP application:

```
$result = mysql_query('DESC `phase`');
if(is_resource($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($column =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($column['Field'] === 'Name'){
            $comment_query = "ALTER TABLE `phase` CHANGE `{$column['Field']}` `{$column['Field']}` {$column['Type']} CHARACTER SET COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci {$column['Default']} COMMENT 'comment here...'";
            $result = mysql_query($comment_query);
            echo ($result) ? 'Added comment' : 'Failed to add comment';
            break;
        }
    }
} else{
    echo 'Not a table description result';
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i will not be able to generate this using my php application as i want to update it using my php application

Comment: @Abhilash: I updated my answer, try it, I haven't tested here, but it should work just fine.